# necesito enviar un correo eletrónico desde un trigger en oracle

Tags: oracle-11g

Necesito enviar un correo desde un trigger en Oracle (estoy haciendo una aplicacion de 3 capas con el *Oracle 11g*) y dicho trigger está hecho sobre la tabla que llamé `transferencia`.

Este es el código del trigger:

```
create or replace trigger llega_transfer
before insert on transferencia
for each row
is
begin
insert into exhibicion values(:new.cod_exhibicion, :nombre_exhibicion);
....
insert into transferencia values(:new.cod_transferencia,:new.cod_exhibicion,:new.fecha_entrada,:new.fecha_devolucion);
end;
```

Necesito ayuda para enviar el correo de la llegada de la transferencia.

Comment: neesitas enviar correos o programar un triger??

Answer (score 1):

lo enviaremos via gmail:

> **nota:** "en tu caso seria configurarlo con tu servidor de correo si lo poses"

primero necesitamos un tunnel vpn a **gmail** "si poses un correo propio es `opcional` esta parte.":
https://www.stunnel.org/downloads.html
una vez descargado lo instalamos en el servidor donde este oracle instalado
y nos vamos a la ruta de instalacion:
creamos un archivo llamado `stunnel.conf` dentro tendra lo siguiente y reiniciamos la aplicacion:

```
[SSMTP]
CLIENT = YES
ACCEPT  = 1925
CONNECT = SMTP.GMAIL.COM:465
```

ahora necesitaremos ir a gmail.com
https://myaccount.google.com/security
al final en `Permitir el acceso de aplicaciones poco seguras:` colocamos que SI

ahora necesitaremos configurar las reglas de acl:

```
    -- create acl
    begin
            dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl (
                    acl             => 'gmail.xml',
                    description     => 'Normal Access',
                    principal       => 'CONNECT',
                    is_grant        => TRUE,
                    privilege       => 'connect',
                    start_date      => null,
                    end_date        => null
            );
    end;
    /
    -- add priviliege to acl
    begin
      dbms_network_acl_admin.add_privilege (
      acl       => 'gmail.xml',
      principal    => 'PUBLIC',
      is_grant    => TRUE,
      privilege    => 'connect',
      start_date    => null,
      end_date    => null);
    end;
    /
    -- assign host, port to acl
    begin
      dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl (
      acl => 'gmail.xml',
      host => 'localhost',
      lower_port => 1925,
      upper_port => 1925);
    end;
    /
```

*ahora necesitaremos crear el paquete:*

```
create or replace package send_mail
is
   g_smtp_host      varchar2 (256)     := 'localhost';
   g_smtp_port      pls_integer        := 1925;
   g_smtp_domain    varchar2 (256)     := 'gmail.com';
   g_mailer_id constant varchar2 (256) := 'Mailer by Oracle UTL_SMTP';
   -- send mail using UTL_SMTP
   procedure mail (
      p_name in varchar2
    , p_sender in varchar2
    , p_recipient in varchar2
    , p_subject in varchar2
    , p_message in varchar2
   );
end;
/

create or replace package body send_mail
is
   -- Write a MIME header
   procedure write_mime_header (
      p_conn in out nocopy utl_smtp.connection
    , p_name in varchar2
    , p_value in varchar2
   )
   is
   begin
      utl_smtp.write_data ( p_conn
                          , p_name || ': ' || p_value || utl_tcp.crlf
      );
   end;
   procedure mail (
      p_name in varchar2
    , p_sender in varchar2
    , p_recipient in varchar2
    , p_subject in varchar2
    , p_message in varchar2
   )
   is
      l_conn           utl_smtp.connection;
      nls_charset    varchar2(255);
   begin
      -- get characterset
      select value
      into   nls_charset
      from   nls_database_parameters
      where  parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
      -- establish connection and autheticate
      l_conn   := utl_smtp.open_connection (g_smtp_host, g_smtp_port);
      utl_smtp.ehlo(l_conn, g_smtp_domain); 
      utl_smtp.command(l_conn, 'auth login');
      utl_smtp.command(l_conn,utl_encode.text_encode('user@gmail.com', nls_charset, 1));
      utl_smtp.command(l_conn, utl_encode.text_encode('passworgmail', nls_charset, 1));
      -- set from/recipient
      utl_smtp.command(l_conn, 'MAIL FROM:<'||p_sender||'>');
      utl_smtp.command(l_conn, 'RCPT TO: <'||p_recipient||'>');
      -- write mime headers
      utl_smtp.open_data (l_conn);
      write_mime_header (l_conn, 'Reply-To', p_sender);
      write_mime_header (l_conn, 'From',''|| p_name ||'<'||p_sender||'>');
      write_mime_header (l_conn, 'To', p_recipient);
      write_mime_header (l_conn, 'Subject', p_subject);
      write_mime_header (l_conn, 'Content-Type', 'text/html');
      --write_mime_header (l_conn, 'X-Mailer', g_mailer_id);
      utl_smtp.write_data (l_conn, utl_tcp.crlf);
      -- write message body
      utl_smtp.write_data (l_conn, p_message);
      utl_smtp.close_data (l_conn);
      -- end connection
      utl_smtp.quit (l_conn);
   exception
      when others
      then
         begin
           utl_smtp.quit(l_conn);
         exception
           when others then
             null;
         end;
         raise_application_error(-20000,'Failed to send mail due to the following error: ' || sqlerrm);  
   end;
end;
/
```

*por ultimo provamos:*

```
begin
   send_mail.mail('name sender.','reply@gmail.com', 'user@gmail.com', 'email example', '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="color:blue;">ejemplo envio de correo</h1>
</body>
</html>');
end;
/
```

Comment: estuve revisando tu código pero tengo estos errores.....
no se si puedes darme una mano, soy nuevo en el tema de plsql Error(4,4): PL/SQL: Item ignored
Error(5,28): PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_SMTP' must be declared
Error(23,24): PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_SMTP' must be declared
Error(23,24): PL/SQL: Item ignored
Error(32,7): PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed